# Drawing offscreen with Quartz2D and using the result as an OpenGL ES texture in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, quartz-graphics, texturing, off-screen

According to the docs I've read, offscreen drawing with a CGLayer is the highest performance way to do Quartz 2D drawing because it allows the drawing to be stored/managed by the GPU and VRAM.

When I'm finished drawing I'd like to grab the pixel buffer from the CGLayer and use it as an OpenGL texture.

I know how to create the texture with a pixel buffer.

I've seen examples of offscreen rendering to a CGBitmapContext, retrieval of pixels, and then creating a texture with those pixels.

The Quartz 2D programming guide suggests that drawing to a CGBitmapContext is slow and done in software (no GPU involvement) so I'm avoiding that path.

So, they say to get fast drawing I need to draw in that CGLayer.  How do I get the pixels back in a memory buffer that I can send into glTexImage2D() ?

Thanks much !